# switch from asp.net mvc 1.0 -> 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, s#arp-architecture

I am currently trying to move from asp.net mvc 1.0 to 2.0 in an existing solution (s#arp framework). Most things seem to work fine apart from unexplainable error messages:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0828: Cannot assign method group to anonymous type property

Source Error:

Line 10:             <p>
Line 11:                 [
Line 12:                 <%=Html.ActionLink("Edit", "GlobalQualitativeFeatureForm", new { Id = Model.Id })%>
```

Is the mvc 2.0 syntax different? This is a strongly typed view which definately gets the object.

I also seem to have to do:

```
<% if (Model != null) {%>
        <%= Html.Grid(Model as IEnumerable<bla.Core.Lab>)
            .Sort(ViewData["sort"] as GridSortOptions)
```

where before a simple:

```
<% if (Model != null) {%>
        <%= Html.Grid(Model)
```

would have been enough. I do a:

```
<add namespace="bla.Core"/>
```

in web.config though.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Christian

PS:

I also get:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'

Source Error:

Line 8:      
Line 9:      <% if(Model != null) { %>
Line 10:         <% using (Model.Id == 0 ? Html.BeginForm("CreateLab", "Labs", "Post") : Html.BeginForm("UpdateLab", "Labs", "Post"))
Line 11:            { %>
Line 12:
```

does this ring a bell?

Comment: Have you managed to resolve your other issues related to correct DLL versions? If not, MVCContrib may be playing a part

Comment: MVCContrib seems to work fine now . I can sort and page whilst using strongly typed views.

Comment: It all seems to have to do with strongly 'typedness' => Model. In my mvccontrib grid views I had to do a "Model as IEnumerable<bla.Core.Lab>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The s#arp architecture comes with two web.config files. I have overlooked the one in the Views folders and adjusted the version of asp.net mvc.